# Magento 2: SOAP Services Authentication

Tags: magento2, soap

I am trying to integrate Magento 2 using SOAP services.  I am bit struggling on the initial steps to authenticate to the store.

My objective is to connect to Magento 2 store and get the customer details of the given E-mail address.

I created an Integration point with the proper privileges.  I got the 4 secret tokens and passwords as below.

```
Consumer Key: aaa
Consumer Secret: bbb
Access Token: cccc
Access Token Secret: ddd
```

How can I first authenticate?

Answer (score 2):

You should use Access Token as a Bearer token:

```
$opts = ['http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . $token]];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlUrl);
$soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
$soapClient->setStreamContext($context);
```

More details are in official documentation:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0//get-started/gs-web-api-request.html

Comment: My client is a PHP client and should I use Zend framework as mandatory to create the soapClient?

Comment: It is not mandatory to use Zend, just use [\SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) and specify correct Authorization header during request.

Comment: @AlexPaliarush I cant able to use the normal PHP SoapClient.  If possible can be give me a code snippet????

Comment: I have just wasted hours on a similar problem and I am not sure my php & webserver support the streamcontext. Anyone know what versions etc. this might work in?

Answer (score 1):

To answer @Malaiselvan and others which fail in using native PHP 7 SoapClient, there is a bug in the Magento 2 documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/soap/soap-web-api-calls.html which states:

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, ['version' => SOAP_1_2, 'context' => $context]);
```

Instead, you should pass 'soap_version' and 'stream_context' parameters, like so:

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl,  ['soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'stream_context' => $context]);
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
try{

    $url = 'http://your-magento-url/soap/default?wsdl&services=customerCustomerRepositoryV1';

         $opts = array(
                'http'=>array(
                    'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer 2fvvl0xyd9kkjliqkumsqxj7niev44ncfc'
                )
            );
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);


        $client = new SoapClient($url,  array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2, 'stream_context'=>$context));

        //Zend_Debug::dump($client->__getFunctions());

        $soapResponse = $client->customerCustomerRepositoryV1GetList(array('searchCriteria'=>''));        
         Zend_Debug::dump($soapResponse);

}catch(SoapFault $f){
    echo "Fault: ".$f->getMessage();
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Why will this work? What will it do? "Code only" answers are not very helpful. Please add at least a little explanation.

Comment: It won't work.   Php's SoapClient refuses to pass the Authentication header when fetching the wsdl.     The wsdl must 1st be retrieved, then referenced locally